# Setting mutt mimetype to handle multiple options

Tags: linux, unix, email, mutt, mime-types

I've configured `.mailcap` for mutt to handle mimetypes of attachments individually, with different 'viewers' over the years which works well, however mailcap can handle only one application per type. I'd like to choose from a set of applications and if possible have a default one.

I suspect that this feature is outside of mailcap's scope. Is there any generic file-handler i could pass data to handle certain types on request and having a default type. (My first thought would be `gnome-open`. This is kind of like 'open file' where right click let's one choose an application, but double click uses the default app.) The tricky part here is that most of mutt's output is into stdout while sometimes the output is to the window manager.

Here is an example mailcap:

```
text/html; elinks -dump -dump-charset utf-8 -default-mime-type text/htm %s; copiousoutput
image/jpeg; jp2a %s; copiousoutput
```

Now while elinks is fine most of the time to render html to stdout, sometimes i'd like to use `firefox` for `html`. Same for jp2a, it's convenient to have ascii by default but sometimes i'd like to use `display` to show the `jpeg` graphically.

Comment: Why do you want multiple? Is it because you want different thing to happen in X and not in X?

Comment: Yes, or use different browsers to render html for example. I've been using mutt with X a lot, it just breaks once you have only terminal available.

Comment: Why don't you simply write a script that will test if you have DISPLAY set, and based on this run either console or graphical browser?

Comment: I'd really like to choose between applications. A script would solve the terminal vs. wm use-case, and it's probably a good start. I'd have to pass and handle the mime types in the script myself to handle choices.

Comment: Check program `urlview`. It's in apt repository in debian/ubuntu, and I guess in other distributions it is available too.